# JSF 2.0 command button generates NullPointerException

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 2.2.1 with JSF 2.0.  I have a page with various labels to display data, some listboxes and a couple of commandButtons.  No matter what I do, whenever I click on a command button in this page, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.inputmask.InputMaskRenderer.getConvertedValue(InputMaskRenderer.java:115)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1030)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:960)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I have no idea why.  Anyone has an idea of what might be causing this?  I am also using entity classes and a managed bean for this page. This is part of the JSF Page:  The error occurs whenever a command button is clicked.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/   xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <f:view>
        <h:head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/masterpage.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/requests.css" />
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <h:form prependId="false" >
                <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
                <p:panel id="pnlMain" widgetVar="pnlMain" style="width: 100%; font-size: 15px; text-align: left" header="Request Detail">
               .
               .
               .
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">

                            </td>
                            <td align="right">
                                <p:commandButton id="btnViewComment" widgetVar="btnViewComment" ajax="false" value="View Selected" />
                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <p:panel id="pnlSupportingDocs" widgetVar="pnlSupportingDocs" header="Supporting Documents" >
                        <div>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" >
                                        <h:selectOneListbox id="lstDocs" style="width: 300px; height: 100px" value="#{MyDocuments.doId}" >
                                            <f:selectItems value="#{RequestSearch.selectedRequest.documentCollection}" var="d" itemLabel="#{d.doName}" itemValue="#{d.doId}" />
                                        </h:selectOneListbox>
                                    </td>
                                    <td valign="bottom" >
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <p:commandButton id="btnViewSelected" style="font-size: 8px; width: 150px" widgetVar="btnViewSelected" value="View Selected" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <p:commandButton id="btnRemoveSelected" style="font-size: 8px; width: 150px" widgetVar="btnRemoveSelected" value="Remove Selected" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <p:fileUpload id="btnNewDoc" widgetVar="btnNewDoc" update="messages" allowTypes="*.*" description="All Files" fileUploadListener="#{MyDocuments.handleFileUpload}" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </p:panel>
                    <p:panel id="pnlFinalization" widgetVar="pnlFinalization" header="Final Evaluation" >
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" >
                                    <h:outputLabel id="lblComments" style="font-size: 12px" value="Comments:" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p:inputTextarea id="txtComments" widgetVar="txtComments" style="width: 300px" maxHeight="600" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h:outputLabel id="lblFinalAdjAmt" style="font-size: 12px" value="Final Adjustment Amt:" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p:inputMask id="txtFinalAdjAmt" widgetVar="txtFinalAdjAmt" mask="$9999999.99" style="width: 100px; text-align: right" maxlength="15" />
                                </td>
                                <td width="100px" >

                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <h:outputLabel id="lblFinalStatus" style="font-size: 12px" value="Final Status:" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <h:selectOneMenu id="cmbStatus" value="#{theStatus.reqStatus}" >
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{theStatus.finalStatus}" />
                                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p:commandButton id="btnSave" widgetVar="btnSave" value="Save" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:panel>
                <p:dialog header="Print Forms" id="pf" widgetVar="pf" modal="true" width="450" height="300">  
                    <iframe src="../PopUpPages/FormMenu.jsf" width="400" height="250" />
                </p:dialog>
                <p:dialog header="Comment Detail" id="cd" widgetVar="cd" modal="true" width="450" height="300" >

                </p:dialog>
                <p:dialog header="Supporting Documents" id="sd" widgetVar="sd" modal="true" width="600" height="800" >
                    <iframe src="../PopUpPages/SupportingDoc.jsf" width="590" height="650" scrolling="true" />
                </p:dialog>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

Comment: please show us the jsf page and the bean. i think this is due to some invalid el.

Comment: I will post the bean and jsf page as soon as this page lets me.  Since I'm new posting I have to wait 6 hours from the time of post

Comment: As per your JSF code, didn't you have had the chance to cut down that monster piece into the smallest possible view sample which still reproduces the problem? See also http://sscce.org

Comment: The stack trace clearly states an issue with the InputMask converter.  Try reproducing the problem on an example page with just an input mask component and post back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<p:inputMask>` has no `value` attribute:

```
<p:inputMask id="txtFinalAdjAmt" widgetVar="txtFinalAdjAmt" mask="$9999999.99" style="width: 100px; text-align: right" maxlength="15" />
```

Add this attribute and it should work.